# Image retrieval using array

Tags: matlab

I am working on a project called image retrieval using sift where I want to retrieve images from file system. The logic I use is:

1. pass image filename to a function.
2. check for a condition to be satisfied.
3. If satisfied store the filename in an array

When I display the array I get the filenames eg. F:\SIFT_Yantao\demo-data\batting.jpg and the length of the array as 36 now my problem is how should I extract the filename from that array and display it? if I use for loop as..

```
    for j=1:numel(array)
```

I am getting 36 elements in my array whereas it is just the name of 1 image...

Answer (score 2):

A string is an array of type `char`, so you are trying (essentially) to loop over the characters in the string. If you want to create an array of strings, each of which may have a different length, then you need to use a [cell array of strings](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/matlab_prog/cell-arrays-of-strings.html). An example is the following:

```
myArray = {'C:\some\path\to\a\file.ext', 'C:\some\path\to\another\file.ext'};
for jj = 1:numel(myArray)
    disp(myArray{jj}); % Display each element
end
```

To append to an existing cell array, you would do:

```
myArray = {}; % Initialise empty cell array
for myLoopCounter = something
    myArray = [myArray {theNewString}];
end
```

If you know how many items the array will have before the loop, then you can use

```
myArray = cell(numberOfElements, 1);
for myLoopCounter = something
    myArray{myLoopCounter} = theNewString;
end
```

Comment: How can i add the values dynamically toa cell array of strings?

Comment: now when i display the cell array i am getting ans as  []    [1x36 char]     []    [1x40 char]  where it should have been the names of the files...

Comment: Well that is exactly what you should expect to see. MATLAB will not display the full string in a cell array if it's too long to fit on the screen in one line, it will display the size of the array and the type - which is what it has done. Also, there must be something funky about the way you're building the array, because you've got empty matrices in the cell array before each string.